# wx Widgets multiple errors in Windows 10

Tags: wxwidgets

I have downloaded wxWidgets-3.0.2 and am trying to create a simple FRAME from the main program.
Unfortunately I am receiving multiple errors that are all to do with wxWidgets, NOT my code. This is odd as I am lead to believe wxWidgets should work.
Here are some of the errors I am getting:

```
*\msw\chkconf.h(19): Error! E080: col(10) "wxUSE_ACTIVEX must be defined."
\msw\chkconf.h(394): Error! E080: col(13) "wxUSE_DATAOBJ requires wxUSE_OLE"
\msw\chkconf.h(414): Error! E080: col(13) "wxMediaCtl requires wxActiveXContainer"
\chkconf.h(1630): Error! E080: col(13) "wxRearrangeCtrl requires wxCheckListBox"
\vector.h(197): Error! E148: col(71) access to private member 'reverse_iterator::m_ptr' is not allowed
\vector.h(187): Note! N392: col(21) definition: 'wxToolTip * * wxVector<wxToolTip *>::reverse_iterator::m_ptr'*
```

Why am I receiving these messages when wxWidgets is supposed to be ready to go?

Comment: @DavidMillarPowell, are you getting compiling your own code or wxWidgets?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured properly? If not try [this link](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Install)  to configure on Windows. Also, you can try to use Linux. It is much easier to set up WxWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

High level steps to installing wxWidgets:

- Download ( you appear to have done this )
- Build library ( I cannot tell if you have done this )

  -OR-
- Download binary built libraries if available for your compiler ( what compiler are you using - you haven't told us! )
- Build one or two of the sample programs ( It really does not look like you have done this )

NOT UNTIL you have completed all these steps are you "ready to go"